# Simple table manipulation using python

Tags: python, database, csv

I'm  trying python for some quick scripting.

I've to create a nx3 array like

```
[["file_name1", "func_name1", 0],
["file_name1", "func_name2", 1],
["file_name2", "func_name1", 0],
["file_name3", "func_name1", 1]]
```

I've extracted the individual elements running through a loop and added to a list like above. I have to create a report by summing all the boolean values for a particular file_name. How do I do that? Please help.

Extraction code:

```
 db = []
 #extract the file_name, api_name
  for line in open("apiList.txt"):
    columns = line.split(" ")
    r = re.compile('file_(.*?).c')
    m = r.search(columns[-1])
    if m:
      file_name = m.group(1)

    func_name = columns[-2]
    flag = 0
    db.append([file_name,func_name,flag])
```

apilist.txt:

```
void init ..\src\file_mod1.c
void test ..\src\file_mod1.c
```

Comment: can you show apiList.txt or atleast the format?

Comment: What do you expect that code to do?  What does it do instead?  What is the difference?  Just showing the code doesn't help if you don't explain what the problem is.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the apilist.txt.. Actually saving to the list works fine.. I'm not sure how to process the list after I've saved it.. The next step after this is to read an output log file and see if the func_name is present. If present i've to update the flag to 1.. And finally I've to create a report saying these many functions got executed and these didn't..

Comment: I've to sum all the flag values under a single file_name.. I'm not sure how to do that..

Comment: So what's your expected output for the example apiList.txt you showed

Comment: initially the db would be `[[mod1,init,0],[mod1,test,0]]`.. if init is found on the output log i need to update the list to `[['mod1','init',1],['mod1','test',0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the elements with a particular name:

```
FILE_NAME=0
FUNC_NAME=1
BOOL_VALUE=2

db = [
    ["file_name1", "func_name1", 0],
    ["file_name1", "func_name2", 1],
    ["file_name2", "func_name1", 0],
    ["file_name3", "func_name1", 1],
]

list_fn1 = [grp for grp in db if grp[FILE_NAME] == "file_name1"]

sum_fn1 = sum([e[BOOL_VALUE] for e in list_fn1])
```

From another comment of yours:

```
import random
new_bool = random.choice([True, False])

# This works because the sublists are shared (obj=ref) between the two lists.    
for e in list_fn1:
    e[BOOL_VALUE] = new_value

# This is the hard way:
for e in db:
    if e[FILE_NAME] == "file_name1":
        e[BOOL_VALUE] = new_Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries would by my go to.  This creates a dictionary, tests if file_name exists, and if it does add the flag, if it doesn't set the flag.

```
>>> lst = [["file_name1", "func_name1", 0],
           ["file_name1", "func_name2", 1],
           ["file_name2", "func_name1", 0],
           ["file_name3", "func_name1", 1]]
>>> dic = {}
>>> for each in lst:
      if each[0] in dic:
        dic[each[0]] += each[2]
      else:
        dic[each[0]] = each[2]
```

Output:

```
>>> dic
{'file_name1': 1, 'file_name3': 1, 'file_name2': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work. I've one more question: How do I update the flag value in the list by searching by func_name?

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by that; for each file_name you want it to keep track of every time the func_name was counted?

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd
>>> data = [["file_name1", "func_name1", 0],
... ["file_name1", "func_name2", 1],
... ["file_name2", "func_name1", 0],
... ["file_name3", "func_name1", 1]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> res = df.groupby(0).size()
>>> res['file_name1']
2
>>> res['file_name2']
1
>>> res['file_name3']
1
>>>
```

Change flag where first column contains file_name2 and second column contains func_name1

```
>>> df.iloc([(df[0]=='file_name2') & (df[1]=='func_name1')])[2] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work. I'm not sure about this: I need to search for func_name1 in file_name2 in data and update the flag value to 1. How do I do that?

Comment: is there a way to search and update the list without using pandas?

Comment: You may check the answer of @austin-hastings